# Contact intent with multiple select

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to open contact intent and let to the user to select multipile contacts
The intent call:

```
Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts"));
pickContactIntent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); // Show user only contacts / phone numbers
startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
```

With this method the user can select only one contact person .. How can I allow him to choose a lot of contacts and then get all the numbers he chose?

Answer (score 6):

There are two was to do so!

1.Set MAX pick limit in intent:

```
public static final int REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACT = 1;
public static final int  MAX_PICK_CONTACT= 10;

private void launchMultiplePhonePicker() { 

    Intent phonebookIntent = new Intent("intent.action.INTERACTION_TOPMENU");
    phonebookIntent.putExtra("additional", "phone-multi");
    phonebookIntent.putExtra("maxRecipientCount", MAX_PICK_CONTACT);
    phonebookIntent.putExtra("FromMMS", true);
    startActivityForResult(phonebookIntent, REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACT);

 }

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACT) {

            Bundle bundle =  data.getExtras();

            String result= bundle.getString("result");
            ArrayList<String> contacts = bundle.getStringArrayList("result");

            Log.i(TAG, "launchMultiplePhonePicker bundle.toString()= " + contactsPick.toString() );
        }
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Note: it may be different on every OS version and device, and might not work on all of them.

OR

2. Do it in this way:

   Read the Contacts programmatically and display them in a ListView in your Activity and then use Checkboxes in the ListView items and allow multiple items to be selected.

e.g. How you can reads your system contacts:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null); 
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)); 
    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    if("1".equals(hasPhone) || Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) { 
        // You know it has a number so now query it like this
        Cursor phones = myActivity.getContentResolver().query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId, null, null); 
        while (phones.moveToNext()) { 
            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            int itype = phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));

            final boolean isMobile =
                itype == ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE ||
                itype == ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK_MOBILE;

            // Do something here with 'phoneNumber' such as saving into 
            // the List or Array that will be used in your 'ListView'.

        } 
        phones.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer..Thanks Hamad i was really struggling with this for a long time. I wonder why people have not upvoted this until now!!